# Python issues inserting data into SQL

Tags: python, python-3.x

The code below is having issues with the insert. I have used this insert script before and not gotten any issues. I have 2 prints to validate data columns on the dataframe and that I make it inside the if condition but the insert fails due to type issue with a float but all the columns are varchar. My question then becomes what is wrong with my insert.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import pyodbc
import time

### Insert process
def sqLInsert(data,switch):
    start_time = time.time()
    conn_str = (
        r'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};'
        r'SERVER=SomeServer;'
        r'DATABASE=SomeDatabase;'
        r'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
    )
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)

    cursor = cnxn.cursor()

    if 'Defensive' in switch:
        print(data)
        data.columns = data.columns.to_flat_index().map('_'.join)
        print(data)
           
        for index,row in data.iterrows():
            cursor.execute('INSERT INTO dbo._DATA_Defensive([caption],[player],[tackles_TOT],[tackles_solo],[tackles_sacks],[tackles_TFL],[misc_PD],[misc_QBHTS],[misc_TD],[misc_UnNamed],[gameid]) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)', 
                        row['caption_player'],
                        row['player_player'],
                        row['tackles_TOT'],
                        row['tackles_SOLO'],
                        row['tackles_SACKS'],
                        row['tackles_TFL'],
                        row['misc_PD'],
                        row['misc_QB HTS'],
                        row['misc_TD'],
                        row['misc_Unnamed: 8_level_1'],
                        row['gameid_player']
                        )
        cnxn.commit()
        cursor.close()
        cnxn.close()
        return data

url = 'https://www.espn.com/nfl/boxscore/_/gameId/401326313'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")


for table in soup.select('article.boxscore-tabs table'):
    gameid = url[(url.find("gameId",0))+7:len(url)]
    caption = '_'.join(table.parent.select_one('.table-caption').text.split(' '))
    df = pd.read_html(table.prettify(),index_col=0)[0].rename_axis('').reset_index()
    df.insert(0, 'caption', caption)
    df['gameid'] = gameid

    df.rename( columns={'':'player'}, inplace=True )
    df1 = sqLInsert(df,caption)
```

My Error below states issue with float type issue but all the columns on the table are varchar

```
('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Parameter 13 (""): The supplied value is not a valid instance of data type float. Check the source data for invalid values. An example of an invalid value is data of numeric type with scale greater than precision. (8023) (SQLExecDirectW)')
```

See Table schema below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[_DATA_Defensive](
    [EntryID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CreationTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [caption] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [player] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [tackles_TOT] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [tackles_solo] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [tackles_sacks] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [tackles_TFL] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [misc_PD] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [misc_QBHTS] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [misc_TD] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [misc_UnNamed] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [gameid] [varchar](50) NULL
)
```

Comment: The error sounds like one of the parameters was empty. Have you checked that?

Comment: The error message is rather confusing but my guess is that it's because row['misc_Unnamed: 8_level_1'] == NaN

Comment: Interesting, wont Nan just be NULL once I try to insert? Ok I guess i could do blank or 0 if Nan value. What would you suggest?

Comment: Think your on to something tried fillna(0) and got error 'float' object has no attribute 'fillna'.